# Mysql Query Two Foreign Key To One Primary Key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table : history_tickets & users

Tabel 1 : history_ticket

```
history_id   |  id_klien    | id_staf   | message
  11         |     77       |   NULL    |  text
  12         |    NULL      |    1      |  text
  13         |     77       |   NULL    |  text
```

Tabel 2 : users

```
user_id   |  name    | group   
  1       |   john   |  staff  
  77      |   dion   |  member
```

I want result like this :

```
history_id   |  message | user_id  |  name   | group
  11         |    text  |   77     |  dion   |  member
  12         |    text  |    1     |  john   |  staf
  13         |    text  |   77     |  dion   |  member
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.HISTORY_ID,
        a.MESSAGE,
        COALESCE(a.ID_KLIEN, a.ID_STAF) UserID,
        COALESCE(b.name, c.name) name,
        COALESCE(b.group, c.group) `group`
FROM    history_ticket a
        LEFT JOIN users b
            ON a.id_klien = b.user_ID
        LEFT JOIN users c
            ON a.id_staf = c.user_ID
```

- [SQLFIddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ba8fe/5)

Answer (score 2):

You need to `JOIN` the tables:

```
select h.history_id,
  h.message,
  u.user_id,
  u.name,
  u.group
from history_ticket h
left join users u
  on h.id_staf = u.user_id
  or h.id_klien = u.user_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ba8fe/3)